# How can i send messages or files to discord without client triggers?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

i want the send files to my discord channel.

But i want the send this file depend of some conditions and this conditions is **not related with discord messages**.

```
def run_discord_bot():
    TOKEN = '111111111111111111111'
    intents = discord.Intents.default()
    intents.message_content = True
    client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

    @client.event
    async def on_ready():
        print(f'{client.user} is now running!')

    @client.event
    async def on_message(message):

        if message.author == client.user:
            return

        await send_message(message, user_message)



    client.run(TOKEN)
```

**on_message** and **on_ready** methods are trigged with **discord client**.

I don't want the trigger function with channel messages or any client event.
Can i create a function here and can i trigger this function from another script ?
Just like an API.

I tried something like this:

```
import discord

intents = discord.Intents.default()
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

client.login(TOKEN)

channel = client.get_channel(1111111111111)

channel.send('Hello Discord!')
```

but its returning error

```
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Client.login' was never awaited
  client.login(TOKEN)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to filter your `on_message` with for example a user id.

If you don't want to do that you could theoretically have a flask api and a discord bot run from the same script like this:

```
def flask_loop():
    app.run(port=26389, host="0.0.0.0")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=flask_loop)
    t2.start()
    bot.run(DCB_TOKEN)
```

This would allow you to call discord commands from an api endpoint.